# SonarQube - Show code coverage considering multiple projects

Tags: java, junit, sonarqube, code-coverage, sonarqube-scan

I have a Java project consisting on multiple modules. Some functions for a common package are tested within the other modules. Sonar only shows the code coverage tested inside each package, how can I tell it to search in all the modules?

I am using SonarQube 4.5.4, Java 8 and JUnit 4.12

Comment: could you give more information sonarqube version jdk sonar runner or scun ...!

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide SonarQube with a single JaCoCo report aggregating data from all the modules.

In the parent POM, define a location for this aggregated JaCoCo report:

```
<properties>
  <sonar.jacoco.reportPath>${project.basedir}/../target/jacoco.exec</sonar.jacoco.reportPath>
</properties>
```

and configure JaCoCo (especially `<destFile>`)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.6.201602180812</version>
    <configuration>
      <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
      <append>true</append>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>agent</id>
        <goals>
          <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

In each module, tell JaCoCo to aggregate the coverage data to this global JaCoCo report file:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <destFile>${sonar.jacoco.reportPath}</destFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can have a look at this project: https://github.com/racodond/sonar-css-plugin that produces an aggregated JaCoCo report used by SonarQube: https://sonarqube.com/dashboard/index?id=org.codehaus.sonar-plugins.css%3Acss